# Make country-specific travel questions more likely to be advertised in language and usage sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange

It'd be nice if questions about travel to country X were more likely to appear in the cross-site ads in "X Language & Usage" stack exchanges. For example, [japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan) questions appear on Japanese Language & Usage, and [germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany), [austria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austria), etc. on German Language & Usage.

People on the relevant Language & Usage web site are either more likely to want to know information about the corresponding country, or are more likely to be able to provide information about the corresponding country.

For those not familiar with cross-site ads, the following is an example of a cross-site ad linking to the Japanese SE (well, except for the minor fact that the ad itself was on the Japanese SE!)

[image: Sample cross-site ad]

I'm not sure what the "secret sauce" of cross-site advertising is, but it seems to be non-random - I see far more ads for certain Stack Exchanges than for others.

Of course, this shouldn't be over-done - only seeing travel questions advertised when you're at a L&U site might become wearisome after a while.

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: I really like this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've talked about much smarter cross-site advertisement, that factors in...

- the audience of the site
- the appeal of the specific question, including its tags
- the "group" the site is in (science, arts, etc)

... but we have yet to get there. As the network grows I am sure the logic of "which house ad is shown on which site?" will become far more sophisticated and hopefully smarter.

Comment: Any updates on this Jeff? I've posted a question on meta.SO with some ideas: **[Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989)**